# Generate File Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

## Generate And Save File On Server Using Javascript

*Can any body help me?* I want to create a **JavaScript Function**. In which...

- When the user enters the data (*In Multiple Fields*) the data is stored.
- When the user clicks the submit button the *system creates a new file* or if the file *already exists* then it edit it's contents [*.txt,.html,.js*).
- And it automatically saves it to the server.

I'm not enough well-trained.

Is this possible? If yes then please somebody help me.

Comment: Check my simple kick-starter tutorial anser!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Manipulating data is done by server, You need to install npm in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The file writing on the server will be done using a server-scripting language such as php or asp.net. Ofcourse, if you want to do this in javascript you could write it in server-script: Node.js

A simple example at my github page : https://github.com/alokrajiv/nodejs_save_kickstarter

In Brief:

HTML *(save as `index.html`)*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>SAVER</title>
</head>
<body>
    LAST SAVE: <span id="res">NOT KNOWN</span>
    <form id="myform">
        Data:<input name="data">
        <button type="submit">SAVE</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = "/data";
        $.post(url, data, function(resp) {
                $("#res").html("SAVED at " + (new Date()));
                console.log(resp);
                });
        });
</script>
</html>
```

Node.js Server (save as `app.js`)

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.post('/data/', function (req, res) {
    var filename = "test.txt";
    var dataToSave = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    console.log(dataToSave);
    fs.unlink(filename, function (err) {
        if (err && err.code !== 'ENOENT')
            throw err;
        fs.writeFile(filename, dataToSave, { flag: 'w' }, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json({ data: "saved" });
        });
    });
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 9001);
```

To run now:
on the console type:

```
npm i express body-parser morgan
node app.js
```

Go to your browser go to `http://localhost:9001`